# I don't understand the behavior of fgets in this example

Tags: c, fgets

While I could use strings, I would like to understand why this small example I'm working on behaves in this way, and how can I fix it ?

```
int ReadInput() {
    char buffer [5];
    printf("Number: ");
    fgets(buffer,5,stdin);
    return atoi(buffer);
}

void RunClient() {
    int number;
    int i = 5;
    while (i != 0) {
        number = ReadInput();
        printf("Number is: %d\n",number);
        i--;
    }
}
```

This should, in theory or at least in my head, let me read 5 numbers from input (albeit overwriting them).

However this is not the case, it reads 0, no matter what.

I understand printf puts a \0 null terminator ... but I still think I should be able to either read the first number, not just have it by default 0. And I don't understand why the rest of the numbers are OK (not all 0).

**CLARIFICATION:** I can only read 4/5 numbers, first is always 0.

**EDIT:**

I've tested and it seems that this was causing the problem:

main.cpp

```
scanf("%s",&cmd);
    if (strcmp(cmd, "client") == 0 || strcmp(cmd, "Client") == 0)
        RunClient();
```

somehow.

**EDIT:**

Here is the code if someone wishes to compile. I still don't know how to fix

http://pastebin.com/8t8j63vj

**FINAL EDIT:**

Could not get rid of the error. Decided to simply add @ReadInput

```
int ReadInput(BOOL check) {
    ...
    if (check) 
       printf ("Number: ");
    ...
```

@ RunClient()

```
void RunClient() {
    ...
    ReadInput(FALSE); // a pseudo - buffer flush. Not really but I ignore 
    while (...) {                    // line with garbage data
        number = ReadInput(TRUE);
        ...
    }
```

And call it a day.

Comment: what happens before you call RunClient? Maybe you have read from the keyboard before so there is something still in the buffer e.g. by doing a scanf()

Comment: buffer itself is empty, but I think my input buffer is not. I would like to flush it, but I understand it causes undefined behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fgets` reads the input as well as the newline character. So when you input a number, it's like: `123\n`.

`atoi` doesn't report errors when the conversion fails.

Remove the newline character from the `buffer`:

```
buf[5];
size_t length = strlen(buffer);
buffer[length - 1]=0;
```

Then use `strtol` to convert the string into number which provides better error detection when the conversion fails.

Comment: Ok, so I have a main.cpp file where I call `RunClient()` could the null terminator from there overlap into fgets ? that would be why I always get 0 (I do expect 0 if `atoi` fails, what I don't expect is 0 for no reason without me being able to input).

Comment: No, `fgets` reads the newline into the buffer. So just get rid of it as in the answer, then do the conversion. `atoi` will work after that. But strtol family functions are better.

Comment: Ok, I will try that right now, but I have to say: I moved the function in main where I didn't have to call it, and it removed the problem. I seriously think somehow the newline character from when I hit "enter" within `main.cpp` somehow caused all of this. (I had `scanf("%s",&cmd);` in main)

Comment: @Kalec The `scanf("%s", &cmd);` leaves the newline in the input buffer. If the next input reader is `fgets`, that finds the newline and is happy, storing `{'\n', '\0' }` in the read buffer. `atoi` converts the string `"\n"` to 0.

Comment: @DanielFischer I got that myself, what I did was to simply ignore the first input data. I would like to know if that's OK or is it conceptually wrong ?

Comment: @Kalec Wasn't clear to me whether you understood how it comes to be, so I explained just in case. After the `scanf`, you have a newline in the input buffer (or another whitespace character followed by whatever), and you must remove it before reading the first number. How you do that is up to you, but if the user entered `"client Ha! You didn't expect this, did you?"` for `cmd`, you are left with more than five characters of junk. So it might be better to clear the input buffer with a `getchar()` loop until you find a newline (or get `EOF`).

Comment: @DanielFischer He could do that, but as long as he doesn't input "client" or "Client", the function still won't be called. And when he does input client, there's only a newline character left in the buffer.

Comment: @Kalec `scanf("%s",&cmd);` <- the `%s` format stops at the first _whitespace_, so that will result in `cmd` (that's an array, right? otherwise, if it is a `char*`, you must get rid of the `&`) holding `{'c', 'l', 'i', 'e', 'n', 't', '\0'}` and the remainder in the input buffer starting with `" Ha! You didn't expect"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
char * fgets ( char * str, int num, FILE * stream );
```

**Get string from stream.**

*Reads characters from stream and stores them as a C string into **str** until (num-1) characters have been read or either a newline or the end-of-file is reached, whichever happens first.*

*A newline character makes **fgets** stop reading, but it is considered a valid character by the function and included in the string copied to str. (This means that you carry \n)*

*A terminating **null** character is automatically appended after the characters copied to str.
Notice that fgets is quite different from gets: not only fgets accepts a stream argument, but also allows to specify the maximum size of str and includes in the string any ending newline character.*

**PD: Try to have a larger buffer.**

Comment: Thank you, I think I'll use gets because that newline character seems to be messing me up.

Comment: Don't use `gets` forget it exists, it will give you problems in future.

Comment: Okay, may I at least ask why ?

Comment: read this complete --> here stackoverflow.com/questions/4309746/safe-alternative-to-gets